SQL запрос для определения объёма данных
Всем привет!
Помогите составить SQL скрипт для определения размера данных в таблицах с группировкой по месяцам.
Например есть таблица "TableNameData" с полями "CreatedOn", "Size".

Запрос для этой таблицы выглядит следующим образом:
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', "CreatedOn"), 'YYYY-MM-DD') Месяц, PG_SIZE_PRETTY(SUM("Size")) Объём, COUNT(*) Количество
FROM "TableNameData"
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', "CreatedOn")
ORDER BY Месяц;



Также есть таблица которая хранит в себе информацию о всех таблицах в БД. В ней есть поля "Name", "Caption".
Необходимо составить запрос который выведет информацию, как в запросе выше, из всех таблиц имя которых содержит 'Data'.

